# How can I cast an object property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple issue, I'm using `TypeScript` with `React` and it works great so far, but I've run into this one little issue. I'm new to `TypeScript` but loving it so far, really reminds of `Go`

I'm trying to create a style and pass it into the style as an object e.g.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export interface NavbarProps {
  title: string;
}

export class Navbar extends React.Component<NavbarProps, undefined> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.navbar}>
        <div style={styles.navbarTitle}>
          <h1 style={styles.navbarTitle}>{ this.props.title }</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Lets it compile properly
let spaceBetween: "space-between" = "space-between";

let styles = {
  navbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    paddingRight: '10px',
    height: '50px',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: "#333",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: spaceBetween
  },
  navbarTitle: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    letterSpacing: "1px"
  }
};
```

if I remove the `let spaceBetween: "space-between" = "space-between"` and try to just do `{ justifyContent: "space-between" }` I get an error because according to the typings for the `CSSProperties Interface` it declares `justifyContent` to be like this:

```
/**
         * Defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items
         * along the main-axis of their container.
         */
        justifyContent?: "flex-start" | "flex-end" | "center" | "space-between" | "space-around";
```

so how can I inline the justifyContent rather than having to make a variable just for the casting.

Thanks.

Actual Error

```
src\public\views\components\navbar\navbar.tsx(11,12): error TS2322: Type '{ display: string; flexDirection: string; paddi
  Types of property 'justifyContent' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"center" | "flex-start" | "flex-end" | "space-between" | "space-around"'.
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the "space-between" string from the definition into your code? It should work by the definition, maybe there is a weird character on the string you are using

Comment: Error in footer of question

Comment: try justifyContent: 'space-between'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the proper type for `styles.navbar`, something like

```
let styles = {
  navbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    paddingRight: '10px',
    height: '50px',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: "#333",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  } as ViewStyle,  //<= here
...
}
```

Comment: What is this called in TypeScript so I can read the docs on adding `as ViewStyle` to the end of an object

Comment: The problem here is that in absence of typing, `justifyContent` will be inferred to `string`which cannot be coerced into the `string literal type`: `'center' | 'flex-start' | ...`

Comment: @Datsik this is called type assertion

Comment: Does this require something in tsconfig? I'm getting the error:
`Cannot find name 'ViewStyle'.`

Comment: @Tyler. It depends how you import React(-native). If you import it with an asterisk (a module) mapped to a name, say React, it might be `React.ViewStyle`. I tend to use the syntax `import { ViewStyle } from 'react-native`

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Thanks, I didn't see that it was React-Native. In @types/react it is CSSProperties instead of ViewStyle.

Answer (score 6):

If you import `React` like this:

`import * as React from "react"`

You can do something like the followings:

```
let styles = {
    navbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingLeft: '10px',
        paddingRight: '10px',
        height: '50px',
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: "#333",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
    } as React.CSSProperties
}

let styles: { [name: string]: React.CSSProperties } = {
    navbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingLeft: '10px',
        paddingRight: '10px',
        height: '50px',
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: "#333",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
    }
}

let styles = {
    navbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row' as "row",
        paddingLeft: '10px',
        paddingRight: '10px',
        height: '50px',
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: "#333",
        alignItems: "center" as "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between" as "space-between"
    }
}
```